# javascript window.open truncates url

Tags: javascript, html

i have an anchor defined as:

```
<div class="some-class" style="float:left;width:50%;">text
<span class="some class" id="myid1"></span>
<span>&nbsp;</span><span><a class="class1" href="javascript:void(0);"
onclick="javascript:MYBuggyMethod()" id="myid2" 
class="button" name="good-name">custom text</a></span>
</div>
```

and my simple method

```
function MYBuggyMethod()
        {   
        var temp = window.open(myurl);  
        }
```

the problem is, window.open opens the url most of the time with the complete url, but some times(very inconsistent, but does happens) opens without any query string params. here is a value of the url at runtime, when it works correctly

```
/my/relativePath/toWebsite/MyMethod?param1=val1&param2=val2
```

the value when it opens incomplete url

```
 /my/relativePath/toWebsite/MyMethod
```

any clue anyone? thanks for ur time!

Comment: Where are you setting myurl. Could be a race condition of some kind if its inconsistent.

Comment: @AJak I have hardcoded myurl at declaration time. to check with what u said, i searched through my entire js file and found no other assignments to it. I really want to know the possibility of browser/js framework specific issue.

Comment: Are you using any JS library?

Comment: @Jay yes many. i observed that it shows correct url when loading starts but it removes the query string by the time page loads

Comment: @AJak: Does `myurl` variable still contains the complete URL (including URL variables)? If not, then you need to debug the your code, especially at the part where the URL might be parsed.

Comment: I have the almost same issue. The url works most of the time, but will get truncated some time after "?" mark. This is 8 years later of OP... Any idea this could happen?